# Starting second fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am learning Kotiln. So, what I wish to achieve is this. I have an MainActivity with container thas shows first fragment (A). From fragment A I wish to open second fragment (B) with button located on fragment A. And then via back button show fragment A again (Add it to stack).

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
                .commitNow()
        }

        val btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonFragment) //null

        btn.setOnClickListener {

            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, SecondFragment.newInstance())
                .commitNow()
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment A:

```
 class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
    }

    //private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        //viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        // TODO: Use the ViewModel
    }

}
```

Fragment B (Same as A):
    class SecondFragment : Fragment() {

```
    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = SecondFragment()
    }

    //private lateinit var viewModel: SecondViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        //viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SecondViewModel::class.java)
        // TODO: Use the ViewModel
    }

}
```

The button is at main_fragment.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use back button navigating between your fragments use `add` instead of `replace`:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
            .addToBackstack(null)
            .commitNow()
```

[Optional] I use these two convenient Extension Function to perform adding and replacing inside my Activity:

```
fun AppCompatActivity.addFragment(fragment: Fragment, containerId: Int) {
    supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .add(containerId, fragment, fragment::class.java.simpleName)
        .commit()
}

fun AppCompatActivity.replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment, containerId: Int) {
    supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(containerId, fragment, fragment::class.java.simpleName)
        .commit()
}
```

---

For the part that you need Add FragmentB to top of FragmentA in your Activity back stack when an event happens inside FragmentA:

You can use Callback Interfaces:

Your fragments define Contracts (Interfaces)

```
FragmentA {
    interface Callback {
        onSomeEventHappened()
    }

    private var listener: Callback? = null

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        if (context is Callback) {
            listener = context
        } else throw Exception()
    }

    fun onSomeClickHappened() {
        listener.onSomeEventHappened()
    }
}
```

Your Activity accepts that contract

```
class MainActivity : FragmentA.Callback {
    override fun onSomeEventHappened() {
        //Replace or Add fragment
    }
}
```